# Windows 10 Parental Control - Impossible to find the username

Tags: windows-10, command-line, parental-controls

I'm trying to limit my son's account.  I run Command Prompt as an administrator, then I use the `net` command:

```
net user fabiute /times: V,18-22;S,18-22;D,18-22
```

The text "Impossible to find the username" appears, but the username is correct. How can I resolve?  I am trying this way because the Family Safety doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You should not have a space between `/times:` and the logon restriction parameters. What happens when you run the command `net user fabiute /times:all`?

Answer (score -1):

You are maybe confusing the display name with the actual account name, try issuing the command 
`net users` 
and check if "fabiute" actually appears in the output.
If not another one of the listed account must be his account and the display name is different then the account name. You can check the display name of an listed account by typing: 
`net user name_from_list`